# JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed in Express as soon as the user logs in, but if I refresh it works perfectly fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I  am creating a React application and the backend using node.js.
I am listing all the steps, starting when the user puting the credentials and how the token is null when it gets verified.
But when I refresh the page the token is valid.

**First Step(If users credentials are correct in the frontend):**

```
if (res.status === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.accessToken)
            console.log(res.data)
            dispatch(login(res.data.user))
            navigate("/admin")
 }
```

**Second step (The token is stored on localstorage, and is valid because I checked on JWT.io)**

[image: Token stored in localstorage]

This is the axios instance that I use to fetch

```
   export default axios.create({
      baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
      headers: {
        token: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`, //I assume this my go null; but when I refresh it loads perfectly fine
      },
```

**Third step (The routes on the backend, there is a middleware "admin_auth", that checks token of the user and verifies it)**

```
router.get("/", admin_auth, GET_ALL_CATEGORIES);
```

**Fourth Step (where token comes null as soon as the user sign in)**

```
const admin_auth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers["token"];
  console.log(token) // NULL WHERE USER HAVE JUST LOGGED IN; BUT WHEN THE USER REFRESH THE TOKEN IS VALID
  if (token) {
    console.log(token + " TOKEN ");
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      ...//more code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what's happening here is that when this code runs for the first time  `token` is not saved in local storage. That's why it's getting null.

```
export default axios.create({
      baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
      headers: {
        token: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`, //I assume this my go null; but when I refresh it loads perfectly fine
      },
```

**Why it's running after the refresh**:

Because it got successfully saved in the local storage the first time and now when the above code runs it gets the token and runs fine.

**Solution:**

Update your `axios` file like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instanceAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
  headers: {
    token: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
  }
});



// update your token in axios instance
export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token ) {
    console.log('[axios] confirm new token update  ===>', token);
    instanceAxios.defaults.headers.common['token'] = `${token}`;
    
  } else {
    delete instanceAxios.defaults.headers.common['token'];
   
  }
};

export default instanceAxios;
```

Now when the user successfully login update your token by calling `setAuthToken` function also import it before use:

```
if (res.status === 200) {
  localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.accessToken)
  setAuthToken(res.data.accessToken);// CALLING THIS FUNCTION
  console.log(res.data)
  dispatch(login(res.data.user))
  navigate("/admin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your axios instance may need to be updated/re-created after a token is received from the server. Initially, when the axios instance is created, the `token` is not yet set in local storage and the value of `token` in the header will be `null`.

After the token is received from the server, you set the `token` key-value pair in local storage, but the axios instance you are using is still using the original value of the `token` key-value pair it loaded when the axios instance was instantiated.

When you reload the page, the axios instance is re-instantiated, and reads the correct value of `token` from local storage, which is why it works after the page is refreshed.

As a result, you will likely need to re-create your axios instance or modify the headers of your existing axios instance after the token has been received from the server and put into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the redux in proper way. You are accessing the token from localStorage and it's not efficient way. You can use [react-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) which help you to automatically manage local storage, you don't have to set localStorage manually.

Or else first verify before navigating that token has been stored or not and then try below code.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function setAuthToken(token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `${token}`;
  }
}
```

Always clean the existing token at initialization, then establish the received one.