# JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed if I use an instance of Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

In this scenario I do not get in backend that token is null( jwt malformed).
And works perfectly fine.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("token")) // ey.....
   const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/admin/categories`, {
          headers: {
            token: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        })
```

In this scenario, I do get that JWT is malformed.

*index.tsx*

```
    import axios_auth from "../../../utils/axios/admin"
console.log(localStorage.getItem("token")) // ey.....
    const res = await axios_auth.get(`/admin/categories`)
```

*admin.ts*

```
import axios from "axios";
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
  headers: {
    token: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
  },
});
```

Comment: most likely your `localStorage` value is not set at the point of generating the `axios` object.

Comment: I just checked, it is stored,
I have explained also here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997610/jsonwebtokenerror-jwt-malformed-in-express-as-soon-as-the-user-logs-in-but-if

Comment: ok, then I suggest you inspect your Network tab in Dev Tools and compare what exactly is different between the two approaches.

Comment: @technophyle, in the faulty one it retuns 
{"success":false,"error":{"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"jwt malformed"}}

In the one that loads, it loads the categories that's it. 
Pretty confusing

Comment: ok good for the response. how about request URL, object & headers?

Comment: Under the const res = axios_auth... 
I have created a console.log(JSON.stringify(res)). But it does not print because It goes to the catch function and I cannot see the ouput

Comment: what I'm asking is you open Network tab and inspect the request details of the two requests and see what's the difference. (that is, Headers and Payload)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250851/discussion-between-n9p4-and-technophyle).